# python flask application in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have deployed a python flask application in EC2 instance.

Now i need to create autoscaling groups so that if some parameter is high i need EC2 to spin up automatically with the flask application.

I can create an AMI of the current EC2 instance and associate IAM role to launch template(autoscaling group).Is this the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would have an AMI (often referred to as Golden AMI or prebaked AMI) that your launch configuration / launch template would reference and autoscale.

If you want to improve this further you could look at setting up [Code Deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) so that the latest version code can be deployed to all instances in the autoscaling group without needing to rebuild another golden AMI.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try AWS Chalice. It's like flask but it automatically wires up to an api gateway and lambda.

https://aws.github.io/chalice/quickstart.html

It may simplify a lot of the deployment for you although lambda obviously comes with some resource constraints. The python looks like this;

```
from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name='helloworld')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

The deploy is simply `chalice new-project helloworld` and then `chalice deploy`.